# Clicking on mails Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help in using selenium driver to click on that mail. I've tried and tried and I'm only getting errors.

I've done this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Email Test").click()
```

but got error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
> ```

**Location of he element**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `find_elements_*` will give a list of all found elements, where `find_element_*` will return only the first find. So try:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Email Test").click()
```

Otherwise, if you want to iterate over the list and click all:

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Email Test"):
  link.click()
```

Comment: Nice, if it works then please click on the large check mark to accept it as answer of the question :-)

Comment: btw using driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Email Test").click() 
can i just do 
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Email T").click() 
that instead and would it work ? 
I'm trying to do a mini project with automation using python

Comment: If there aren't confilicts with the partial link text, would work

Comment: i'd like to get that link out of this :
<p><a href="https://u7489643.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=hB4cQpD2Jk6wglMb-2F-2F2wtnTlRMMsdafqKfkM0SQ423lP0LtzUdQf41s-2BwT4cN1N-2BSLDZ-2BRMucEKlzCl4y1yvQNtCN-3D">https://www.example.to/verify-account?code=1db0f9dc-a400-4e10-8723-a6c8174579b4</a></p> 

how do go about this one